# DOM Parsing Clarification

Tags: java, dom, xmlnode, jaxp

I am going through JAXP DOM trail where there is a DOM Mixed Content model as shown below

```
<sentence>This is an <bold>important</bold> idea.</sentence>
```

It's been explained as below

**Note** - The DOM Node API defines nodeValue(), nodeType(), and nodeName() methods. For the first element node, nodeName() returns sentence, while `nodeValue()` returns **null**. For the first text node, nodeName() returns #text, and nodeValue() returns “This is an ”. The important point is that the value of an element is not the same as its content.

My question is why the `getNodeValue()` invoked on `Element` node returns **null**. What is it supposed to have? What is actually a **value** in `Element` node? If i want to set a value to an element node, how can I do that ? Please explain.

Comment: @Downvoter Can you please leave a comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of an [Element](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html) node is always *null* by design. See the [Node documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) for a list of expected values.

This ultimately comes from the [W3C DOM level 3 design](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-1841493061).

Answer (score 0):

Use [Node.getChildNodes()](http://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getChildNodes__). Mapping the "value" to the same child nodes, would have been a duplicity. It is an awkward API, to "set a value" one has to remove all children, and call appendChild or replace/insert.

Ugly, but w3c predates Java, and somehow it was nice, that Java respected w3c.org by adoption.